# Kotlin null-check bug

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I use Java library. In exception class there is "localizedMessage" field and "description" field. I don't know why, but "description" (which is java String) is recognized as String! by Kotlin, and when "description" is null, condition description == null returns false.
Example of code:

```
mvpView?.showToast(it.description?:it.localizedMessage)
```

or without Elvis:

```
if (it.description.isNullOrBlank()) {
     mvpView?.showToast(it.localizedMessage)
} else {
     mvpView?.showToast(it.description)
}
```

it always tries to show "description", but "evaluate expression" in debug mode returns true on description == null (as expected).

Kotlin version is 1.1.1

Comment: How do you know it showed `description` instead of `localizedMessage`? Maybe both of them are null.

Comment: `String!` is the notation used to indicate that the String comes from Java and, therefore, Kotlin doesn't actually know whether it is nullable or not.

Comment: @glee8e from debugger

Answer (score 1):

The reason was in getter, it returned another string instead of description if description is null.

```
public String getDescription() {
    if (description != null) {
        return description;
    }
    if (UNKNOWN_ERROR.equals(getCode())) {
        return String.format("Received error with code %s", getCode());
    }
    return "Failed with unknown error";
}
```

Comment: Where does this exception come from? The actual `java.lang.Exception` has no `description` property. (And you can accept your own answers.)

Comment: @EugenPechanec from third-party library